# How do I speed up my testing for Android?

Tags: android, android-testing

I have simple TestCases on Android, but they take around 10 seconds to load up and run.  Is there a way for me to bypass the Android testing framework?  So I can just use simple JUnit for regular POJOs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) for non-UI testing.

Comment: This is the best solution, although getting robolectric to play nicely with instrumentation tests will takes a good bit of work.

Answer (score 0):

Jason Atwood at Big Nerd Range published [All in Together: Android Studio, Gradle and Robolectric](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/all-in-together-android-studio-gradle-and-robolectric/).  These are concise instructions and worked for me.  With these instructions you can also run the debugger.

You will find instructions from different sources vary, mostly because of the version differences for this evolving software. When googling be sure to search by most recent date.  It is surprising how slow and fragile simple pojo testing still is, but it's getting better.